# Why is while loop and do while loop not working

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while

I'm making this code to enable the operator buttons if the `lastCharacter` is !== "+", "-", "*", "/".

The expected results are if `lastCharacter` is !== "+", "-", "*", "/". it would enable the operator buttons after being disabled, the operators will be disabled if `lastCharacter` is a operator. the only error I encountered is that after I press one of the operator buttons the entire calculator freezes and the loop is still running and making my browser lag.

I tried using while loop

```
       <div class="operators">
          <button id="add-operator">+</button>
          <button id="subtract-operator">-</button>
          <button id="multiply-operator">&times;</button>
          <button id="divide-operator">&divide;</button>
        </div>

        var string = screenInput.innerHTML
        var lastCharacter = string[string.length - 1]
        console.log(`Last character operators: ${lastCharacter} `) 

        if (lastCharacter === "+") {

            while (lastCharacter === "+") {

                document.querySelectorAll(".operators button").forEach(b => {
                    b.disabled = true
                })

                if (lastCharacter !== "+") {

                    document.querySelectorAll(".operators button").forEach(b => {
                        b.disabled = false
                    })
                    break

                }

            }

        }
```

And do while loop

```
        <div class="operators">
          <button id="add-operator">+</button>
          <button id="subtract-operator">-</button>
          <button id="multiply-operator">&times;</button>
          <button id="divide-operator">&divide;</button>
        </div>

        var string = screenInput.innerHTML
        var lastCharacter = string[string.length - 1]
        console.log(`Last character operators: ${lastCharacter} `) 

        if (lastCharacter === "+") {

            do {
                document.querySelectorAll(".operators button").forEach(b => {
                    b.disabled = true
                })
            } while (lastCharacter === "+")

        }
```

Both loops freeze the calculator and make it unresponsive

P.S there are similar if statements for the other operators

Comment: javascript and html is eventdriven you don't have to make loops for such kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

`lastCharacter` is never being changed to another value.

If you're using the comparison of a variable, in this case `lastCharacter`, as the condition for a `while` loop, you'll need to eventually change the value of that variable if you don't want an infinite loop.

Example:

```
let myvar = 0;

while (myvar < 5) {
    myvar = myvar + 1; // Can also be written as myvar++
}

console.log(myvar); // myvar = 5
```

Comment: True—how do you fix it?